# 3D Cad Viewer for Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, 3d

Does anyone know of a 3D Cad Viewer Component for Visual Studio Win App? Web App would be nice too. I am looking to open .dxfs or .dwgs in the viewer with the ability of turning on features for the user such as panning, rotation, perspective, etc...

Comment: What is your ultimate goal? 3D cad isn't even remotely the intended use of visual studio.

Comment: @whatsisname - I think the OP just wants a CAD viewer component for their application *that's developed in Visual Studio*.

Comment: @ChrisF You are correct. Thanks. We create automation for Cad developers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CAD Import .NET

http://www.cadsofttools.com/en/products/cad_import_.net.html

Comment: Thanks for the link, I will investigate as soon as i get chance.